# Trying to bind volume to a docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I'm trying to mount a volume to a docker container, but I have some problems with it. I have a simple python script in a docker container that creates file "links.json" and I would like to access this file from the filesystem.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

COPY . /srv/app
WORKDIR /srv/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

I have created volume with:

```
docker volume create my-data
```

And I'm running this container with command:

```
docker run --mount source=my-data,target=/srv/app 3743b8d3b043
```

I've tried it on MacOS.

When I wrote: `docker volume inspect my-data`, I got this result:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-08-15T08:30:48Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-data/_data",
        "Name": "my-data",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

But all directories like /var/lib/docker/volumes, and directories of this code are empty.. Do you have any ideas where's the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overwriting all you data in `/srv/app` that you add during the `build` process . you may change your `mount` to use other target as `/srv/app`.

**Update**

start your **container** using:

```
docker run -v /ful/path/folder:/srv/app/data IMAGE
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. I've tried to write my ```links.json``` file into /srv/app/data, built container again and run ```docker run --mount source=my-data,target=/srv/app/data 96c79f28f40d```.. But the directory ```/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-data/_data``` is still empty.. 

In fact the directory /var/lib/docker doesn't exist. Can't be problem in that?

Comment: I think you are on windows ?

Comment: No I'm using MacOS

Comment: OK, on WIndows and mac docker startet inside a VM so the path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` is in your `VM` not the `host`. I suggest you to use `-v /ful/path/folder:/srv/app/data`instead of mount